# All possible combinations within one column in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose we have table Z:

```
X Y
1 A
1 A
2 B
3 B
4 B
```

I would like a list of all possible combinations from X grouped by Y.
How can I achieve that? Many have asked similar questions but cant find something that would work for this problem. The result would return something like this

```
Pairs Y
1,1   A 
2,3   B
2,4   B
3,4   B
```

Comment: Does table Z have a PrimaryKey?  Maybe another field with a unique number to be able to identify records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following Fiddle with your input and a query that returns the output you expected:
[Fiddle to play and test your problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4445d/13)

This is the Query:

```
Select Distinct Case 
         When Z1.X < Z2.X Then 
           To_char(Z1.X) || ',' || To_char(Z2.X) 
         Else
           To_char(Z2.X) || ',' || To_char(Z1.X) 
       End As Pairs,
       Z1.Y

From Z Z1
Join Z Z2 ON Z1.Y = Z2.Y AND Z1.rowid <> Z2.rowid
Order by 2,1
```

Since the table is not specified to have a Primary Key, I had to use rowid in order to avoid combinations of a row with itself. If your table has a Primary Key it would be much better to use the PK instead.